# I want to center align all the text widgets in my app, how can I ? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I want to center align all the text widgets in my application, but I don't want to do this manually in every text widget, is there anyway to do this universally?

```
Text("Hello, World!", textAlign: TextAlign.center);

Text("I am omar!", textAlign: TextAlign.center);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with `DefaultTextStyle` like this:

```
class DefaultTextStyleExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const DefaultTextStyleExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('DefaultTextStyle.merge Sample')),
      // Inherit MaterialApp text theme and override font size and font weight.
      body: DefaultTextStyle.merge(
        style: TextStyle(textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Flutter'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This will be applied to all `Text`s. For more information; [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DefaultTextStyle-class.html)s.